# Specifying config.vm.synced_folder at run time

Tags: vagrant

I'd like to give the user the ability to specify the path to the folder they want to share with the Vagrant box when they provision the machine, eg via a command prompt entry:

```
config.vm.synced_folder USER_SETS_THIS, "/srv/website"
```

Is this possible at all? The idea here is that the folder may not always be in the same place on every host machine.

Comment: Ok, looks like I can use `ENV['foo'] vagrant up`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may use environment variables for that.
something like this:

```
VAR="C:\www" vagrant up
```

in vagrant file:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ENV['VAR'], "/srv/website"
```

I didn't try use this in that way, however, but you may try :)